# How to obtain MailItem from Explorer object

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I need to be able to get the selected MailItem and save on the local hard-drive it while the client is in preview model (i.e. before the user double clicks and opens the email). So I suspect that I need to get the MailItem from the Explorer object but am not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Explorer.Selection` collection to get all selected items. `Explorer` can be retrieved from `Application.ActiveExplorer`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Just a question, once we receive the Selection, why do we access index 1 rather than 0?

Comment: All OOM collections, including Selection are 1 based, not 0. Remember that OOM was introduced in Outlook 97 when pretty much the only language available for scripting was VB or VBA.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again Dmitry!